# Posts made via LinkedIn API don't appear on user's updates

Tags: linkedin-api

I have an application that users can share content to LinkedIn, and I have instances where the request was made out to https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json via POST, containing the token etc. and I got a response back in the usual format, e.g. (anonymised, of course):

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
x-li-request-id: XXXXXXXXXX
Location: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/pal/people/~/network/updates/key=UPDATE-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Vary: *
x-li-format: json
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 01 Dec 2016 10:59:59 GMT
X-Li-Fabric: prod-lva1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Li-Pop: PROD-IDB2
Set-Cookie: lidc="b=VB74:g=524:u=127:i=1480590000:t=1480675453:s=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; Expires=Fri, 02 Dec 2016 10:44:13 GMT; domain=.linkedin.com; Path=/
X-LI-UUID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

{
  "updateKey": "UPDATE-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "updateUrl": "https://www.linkedin.com/updates?discuss=&scope=XXXXXXX&stype=M&topic=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&type=U&a=6sBt"
}
```

The same person has posted content through our application to their account a dozen times, all of the requests to the endpoint returned HTTP 201 responses with UUIDs and update keys/URLs, suggesting to me that the content was successfully sent by us and received by LI.

However of those requests, only half of them actually appear on the user's update list, and of course they have come back to me to ask what the problem is - but I don't know what to do.

It's not consistent in terms of time - it's not like every other request fails or rate limiting is applicable to this application (it's a new application)

If anyone could share light on it, I'd appreciate it, thank you.